# Remove attribute in DOM and jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I still have some problem. In my HTML code I set one DIV to be hidden.

```
<div id="personalProfileWrap" style="visibility: hidden">
```

I changed several times my method in java script and it can be removed this attributed. These are the functions I have tried:

```
var div = document.getElementById("personalProfileWrap");
div.setAttribute("style", "");
//$("#personalProfileWrap").removeAttr("style");
```

I also tested with Dom getElement and still does not work. Don't know where the problem is.

Please for advise.

Comment: It works see here: http://jsfiddle.net/ZzEjL/

Comment: `$("#personalProfileWrap").removeAttr("style");` should work - http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_html_removeattr

Comment: [jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/7aNPa/2/) for comment of @user3388636...

Comment: Why did you tag this "jquery"?

Answer (score 3):

It's a simple `document.getElementById("personalProfileWrap").removeAttribute("style");`

You don't even need jQuery for it. If you only want to remove one or two items, you'll have to do a `.getAttribute("style")` first, and parse through the set styles (semicolon delimiter), remove the one you want, and then do a `.setAttribute("style", newStyleString)`.

Answer (score 0):

The following works for me with jQuery:

```
$("#personalProfileWrap").css("visibility", "inherit");
```

Here my (short) [jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/7aNPa/)